# Run Method after specific Route - Flask

Tags: python, flask

is it possible to call the 'after_request' method only if the specific route '/data_extractor_export' was called or the method 'export'?
Not everytime when the app app routed.

Here is my code

```
@dataextractorController.route('/data_extractor_export', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def export():
    try:

        file_name = request.form.get('file_name')
        file_path = '../MT_Data/Dataset_Download/Data-Extractor/' + str(file_name) + '/'
        file_temp_download = '../WEB_Data/data/Dataset_Upload/' + str(file_name)

        shutil.make_archive(file_temp_download, 'zip', file_path)
        print('Y')
        return send_file(os.path.join(file_temp_download + '.zip'), as_attachment=True)
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[1]
        return error_handler(str(e))


@dataextractorController.after_request
def post_process(response):
    dir = '../WEB_Data/data/Dataset_Upload/'
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        if '.zip' in str(f):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))
    return response
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/skip')
def skip():
    return 'Hello World!'


white_routes = (
    "/skip",
)


@app.after_request
def mid(response):
    if request.path in white_routes:
        return response
    print(request.path)
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000)
```